# Faye Websocket Error Rails 2.2.2 (production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, faye

I have been using Faye on 2.1.3 with no problems, but upon upgrading to 2.2.2 I can only get local instance to work. Production websockets fail.
I replaced the actual server name with blahblahserver.com

Faye Rackup

```
require 'faye'
app = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25)
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
run app
```

Application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application",params[:controller],'http://app-server1.blahblahserver.com:9292/faye/faye.js','data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Helper (send function)

```
def broadcast(channel, &block)
  message = {:channel => channel, :data => capture(&block)}
  uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:9292/faye")
  Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
end
```

In Rails Controller

```
gon.env = Rails.env
```

Listener (Coffeescript)

```
$ ->
  # required when faye listener is present to keep from having hard env changes
  # parallel gon.env = Rails.env in controller must be present
  server_name = undefined
  switch gon.env
    when "production"
     server_name = 'app-server1.blahblahserver.com'
    when "staging"
     server_name = 'si-staging.blahblahserver.com'
    when "development"
     server_name = 'localhost'
  address = 'http://' + server_name + ':9292/faye'

# Listener for this page locally
faye = new (Faye.Client)(address)
faye.subscribe ('/logs/'+gon.property_id+ '/new'), (data) ->
 if getParameterByName('all_open') == "true"
  window.location.href = window.location.href
 else if  gon.today == gon.display_date
  ready(data)
 else window.location.href = window.location.href
return
faye.subscribe ('/logs/'+gon.property_id+ '/alert'), (data) ->
 console.log('pre-ajax')
 $.ajax 'load_customer_messages' ,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  asnyc: false,
  success: (data2) ->
    $('#ajax').click()
 return
return

ready = (data) ->
 eval data
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue lies in Faye's upgrade. Syntax to start now is as follows:

rackup --host [ip address of server] faye.ru -s thin -E production -D
The addition of -- host [ip address] is now required as the rackup no longer listens externally without the ip address.

6 days of frustration, no documentation on the faye site!